# How to save the deleted row into database?

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, import, crud

Sorry Everyone, I re-post my question. The problem is when I press the delete button, the deleted row in jtable disappear, but when I reopen the jtable, this deleted row didn't delete. I think the problem is when delete this row,
this action didn't save into sqlite. Please help me how to implement and solve my problem.
I use MVC to implement CRUD, the database I use sqlite. Besides, I have another question ? How to implements when I press the edit button, the Jtable data will be modified and save into the database.

My code is in the below

```
//Model
public class ClientModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Client> listClient = new ArrayList<Client>();

    **// delete data**
    public void removeSelectedFromTable(JTable clientTable) {
        int[] rows = clientTable.getSelectedRows();
        TableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel) clientTable.getModel();
        for (int row : rows) {
            ((DefaultTableModel) tm).removeRow(clientTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row));
        }
        clientTable.setModel(tm);
    }
```

Demo

```
package demo;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SileaiFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SileaiFrame Jframe = new SileaiFrame();
                    Jframe.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.print(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     * 
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

    public SileaiFrame() throws ParseException {
        setTitle("Database Management");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 793, 477);
        exportMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(exportMenuBar);

        clientLayeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        jftp_0.addTab("Client information", null, clientLayeredPane, null);
        GridBagLayout gbl_clientLayeredPane = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_clientLayeredPane.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        gbl_clientLayeredPane.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        gbl_clientLayeredPane.columnWeights = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                Double.MIN_VALUE };
        gbl_clientLayeredPane.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        clientLayeredPane.setLayout(gbl_clientLayeredPane);
        categoryComboBox = new JComboBox();
        categoryComboBox.setEditable(true);
        categoryComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Activity", "Member", "Donation", "Company"}));
        GridBagConstraints gbc_categoryComboBox = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_categoryComboBox.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_categoryComboBox.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_categoryComboBox.gridx = 1;
        gbc_categoryComboBox.gridy = 0;
        clientLayeredPane.add(categoryComboBox, gbc_categoryComboBox);

        organizationTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_organizationTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_organizationTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_organizationTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_organizationTextField.gridx = 3;
        gbc_organizationTextField.gridy = 0;
        clientLayeredPane.add(organizationTextField, gbc_organizationTextField);
        organizationTextField.setColumns(10);

        nameTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_nameTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_nameTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_nameTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_nameTextField.gridx = 5;
        gbc_nameTextField.gridy = 0;
        clientLayeredPane.add(nameTextField, gbc_nameTextField);
        nameTextField.setColumns(10);

        noTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_noTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_noTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_noTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_noTextField.gridx = 7;
        gbc_noTextField.gridy = 0;
        clientLayeredPane.add(noTextField, gbc_noTextField);
        noTextField.setColumns(10);

        zipTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_zipTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_zipTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_zipTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_zipTextField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_zipTextField.gridy = 1;
        clientLayeredPane.add(zipTextField, gbc_zipTextField);
        zipTextField.setColumns(10);

        addressTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_addressTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_addressTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_addressTextField.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc_addressTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_addressTextField.gridx = 3;
        gbc_addressTextField.gridy = 1;
        clientLayeredPane.add(addressTextField, gbc_addressTextField);
        addressTextField.setColumns(10);

        cellnumberTextField = new JTextField();
        cellnumberTextField.setColumns(10);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_cellnumberTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_cellnumberTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_cellnumberTextField.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_cellnumberTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_cellnumberTextField.gridx = 1;
        gbc_cellnumberTextField.gridy = 2;
        clientLayeredPane.add(cellnumberTextField, gbc_cellnumberTextField);

        faxLabel = new JLabel("fax");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_faxLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_faxLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_faxLabel.gridx = 2;
        gbc_faxLabel.gridy = 2;
        clientLayeredPane.add(faxLabel, gbc_faxLabel);

        faxTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_faxTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_faxTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_faxTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_faxTextField.gridx = 3;
        gbc_faxTextField.gridy = 2;
        clientLayeredPane.add(faxTextField, gbc_faxTextField);
        faxTextField.setColumns(10);

        emailLabel = new JLabel("email");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_emailLabel = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_emailLabel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_emailLabel.gridx = 4;
        gbc_emailLabel.gridy = 2;
        clientLayeredPane.add(emailLabel, gbc_emailLabel);

        emailTextField = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_emailTextField = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_emailTextField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_emailTextField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_emailTextField.gridx = 5;
        gbc_emailTextField.gridy = 2;
        clientLayeredPane.add(emailTextField, gbc_emailTextField);
        emailTextField.setColumns(10);

        JDateChooser birthdayDateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        birthdayDateChooser.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_birthdayDateChooser = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_birthdayDateChooser.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        birthdayDateChooser.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 20);
        gbc_birthdayDateChooser.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_birthdayDateChooser.gridx = 1;
        gbc_birthdayDateChooser.gridy = 3;
        clientLayeredPane.add(birthdayDateChooser, gbc_birthdayDateChooser);

        label = new JLabel("~");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_label.gridx = 2;
        gbc_label.gridy = 3;
        clientLayeredPane.add(label, gbc_label);

        search1DateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_search1DateChooser = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_search1DateChooser.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_search1DateChooser.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_search1DateChooser.gridx = 3;
        gbc_search1DateChooser.gridy = 3;
        clientLayeredPane.add(search1DateChooser, gbc_search1DateChooser);

        JButton createButton = new JButton("add");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_createButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_createButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_createButton.gridx = 4;
        gbc_createButton.gridy = 4;
        clientLayeredPane.add(createButton, gbc_createButton);
        readButton = new JButton("search");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_readButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_readButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_readButton.gridx = 5;
        gbc_readButton.gridy = 4;
        clientLayeredPane.add(readButton, gbc_readButton);

        deleteButton = new JButton("delete");
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cm.removeSelectedFromTable(clientTable);
                categoryComboBox.setSelectedItem("");
                organizationTextField.setText("");
                nameTextField.setText("");
                noTextField.setText("");
                zipTextField.setText("");
                addressTextField.setText("");
                cellnumberTextField.setText("");
                faxTextField.setText("");
                emailTextField.setText("");
                birthdayDateChooser.setDate(null);
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc_deleteButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_deleteButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_deleteButton.gridx = 6;
        gbc_deleteButton.gridy = 4;
        clientLayeredPane.add(deleteButton, gbc_deleteButton);

        updateButton = new JButton("modify");
        updateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        });
        GridBagConstraints gbc_updateButton = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_updateButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_updateButton.gridx = 7;
        gbc_updateButton.gridy = 4;
        clientLayeredPane.add(updateButton, gbc_updateButton);

        clientScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_clientScrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_clientScrollPane.gridwidth = 9;
        gbc_clientScrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_clientScrollPane.gridx = 0;
        gbc_clientScrollPane.gridy = 5;
        clientLayeredPane.add(clientScrollPane, gbc_clientScrollPane);

        clientTable = new JTable();
        clientTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                categoryComboBox.setSelectedItem(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
                organizationTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 1).toString());
                nameTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 2).toString());
                noTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 3).toString());
                zipTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 4).toString());
                addressTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 5).toString());
                landlineTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 6).toString());
                cellnumberTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 7).toString());
                faxTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 8).toString());
                emailTextField.setText(clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 9).toString());
                birthdayDateChooser.setDate((java.util.Date) clientTable.getValueAt(clientTable.getSelectedRow(), 10));
            }
        });

        clientScrollPane.setViewportView(clientTable);
        LoadData();
        activityLayeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dtm.addColumn("category");
        dtm.addColumn("organization");
        dtm.addColumn("name");
        dtm.addColumn("id");
        dtm.addColumn("zip");
        dtm.addColumn("address");
        dtm.addColumn("cellnumber");
        dtm.addColumn("fax");
        dtm.addColumn("email");
        dtm.addColumn("birthday");
        for (Client client : cm.findAll()) {
            dtm.addRow(new Object[] { client.getCategory(), client.getOrganization(), client.getName(), client.getNo(),
                    client.getZip(), client.getAddress(),  client.getCellnumber(), client.getFax(),
                    client.getEmail(), client.getBirthday() });
        }
        this.clientTable.setModel(dtm);
    }
}
```

The complete code in here [http://segmentfault.com/n/1330000003876562]

Comment: `for (int row : rows) {` is a bad idea, as you remove the rows from the model, the row indices will change

Comment: Also, the model should have NOTHING to do with the UI at all, it should never know about

Comment: Your "demo" doesn't compile, nor does it have anything to do with your problem related to removing rows from your model

Comment: Could you tell me what's the error?

Comment: `exportMenuBar` is undefined, `clientLayeredPane` is undefined, `jftp_0` is undefined, I got to about there and just gave up

Comment: Sorry, I delete some codes, because the stackoverflow wants me to reduce my code. and the connectdb class and entity I didn't post.

Comment: Then consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer  this link is my complete code [segmentfault.com/n/1330000003876562]

Comment: Really, I don't think anyone will look at your complete code.  We want a reduced size example that shows the problem.  See the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a quick look at the code you've provided, it occurred to me that I wasn't able to find a `Statment` or a `PreparedStatment` that contained a `DELETE FROM...WHERE` query:

```
PreparedStatement df = ConnectDB.getConn().prepareStatement("DELETE FROM client WHERE organization = ? AND name = ? AND...");
df.execute();
```

If you aren't actually executing a `DELETE FROM...` query on the table or database, nothing is removed. You remove the item from the model, but not from the database. It looks like you will need to add a `PreparedStatment` to `removeSelectedFromTable(JTable clientTable)` that builds and executes a `DELETE FROM...` query. If you are reloading from the database each time you reload the `JTable`, this will resolve your issue.

### WARNING

Notice in my example above, I explicitly used `organization` and `name` in the `DELETE FROM...` `PreparedStatment` example.

**As MadProgrammer stated, if you delete from the table using `(row : rows)`, or something similar based in the indices in the model each time you delete a row, the indices will change.** This means that you will, most likely, end up deleting the wrong set of rows after the first row every time.

I suggest that you build the `DELETE FROM...` with a `WHERE` clause that uses a few of the other columns, such as name and organization, so that you can increase the chance that you are deleting the intended row(s), and remove the rows from the table model accordingly.